# Difference in deflate function between Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, scala, zio

I have 2 deflate functions written in C# and Scala, when running with the same input, the returned byte array has a difference in leading bytes and trailing bytes (the difference between the bytes in the middle is expected by the unsigned/signed bytes mechanism between C# and Scala).

Deflate function in Scala:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.util.zip.{Deflater, DeflaterOutputStream}

import zio._


object ZDeflater {
  val deflater = ZManaged.makeEffectTotal(new Deflater(Deflater.DEFLATED, true))(_.end)

  val buffer = ZManaged.fromAutoCloseable(ZIO.succeed(new ByteArrayOutputStream()))

  val stream = for {
    d <- deflater
    b <- buffer
    s <- ZManaged.fromAutoCloseable(ZIO.succeed(new DeflaterOutputStream(b, d, true)))
  } yield (b, s)

  def deflate(input: Array[Byte]): RIO[blocking.Blocking, Array[Byte]] = stream.use { case (buffer, stream) =>
    for {
      ()    <- blocking.effectBlocking(stream.write(input))
      ()    <- blocking.effectBlocking(stream.flush())
      result = buffer.toByteArray
    } yield result
  }
}
```

Deflate function in C#:

```
private static byte[] Deflate(byte[] uncompressedBytes)
{
    using (var output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var zip = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            zip.Write(uncompressedBytes, 0, uncompressedBytes.Length);
        }

        return output.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Outputs after deflating:
Scala:

```
ZDeflater.deflate(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

124, -111, …, 126, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1
```

C#:

```
Deflate(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data))
125, 145, …, 126, 1
```

Does anyone know what causes the difference between the first and last bytes? Any of your assumptions are very helpful to me. Thank a bunch

P/s: We're having a problem with a situation where C#'s Deflate output works for a specific 3rd part and Scala's output doesn't. So I'm trying to figure out how to make Scala's output to be the same as C#'s

Comment: a quick reaction without research - check out Byte Order Marks.

Answer (score 7):

As documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/Deflater.html), Java's `Deflater` class deflates sequences of bytes into [ZLIB compressed data format](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt). The ZLIB data format wraps compressed data in [DEFLATE data format](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt) with a header and an ADLER-32 checksum after the compressed data.

Microsoft's documentation for [DeflateStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.deflatestrea) is inaccurate about the exact data format. But it actually poduces data in raw DEFLATE data format
and not in ZLIB format ([dotnet-2236](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2236) ). With it, its output is also incompatible
with HTTP's "deflate" transfer encoding, which actually references the ZLIB
data format and not the DEFLATE data format ([RFC-2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-3.5)).

But how can you achive now the same output with Scala and C#?

**A) Write data also in raw DEFLATE format with Scala**

The `Deflater` class has an [overloaded construtor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,boolean)) with
a `nowrap` parameter, that allows to omit the header and the checksum.
Setting this parameter to `true` will lead to compressed data in raw DEFLATE data format. If you should also plan to de-serialize the data in Java, please read the Javadoc of the `Inflater` constructors carefully.

**B) Write data also in ZLIB format with C#** (recommended)

Use .NET's [ZLibStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zlibstream?view=net-6.0) class or any [third-party library](https://developpaper.com/how-to-use-zlib-compression-and-decompression-in-c/) instead of the `Deflater` class, to serialize your data in ZLIB format.

**C) Use GZIP format instead**

GZIP format is comparable to ZLIB, but uses a different header and a different checksum. Both, .NET and Java provide explicit stream classes for it. Although ZLIB's checksum calculation performs better and produces even a smaller header than GZIP, the latter is more common (especially in the web). Main reason for GZIP's popularity is, that Microsoft always had trouble distinguishing between raw DEFLATE and ZLIB resp.HTTP's `deflate` transfer encoding (see ZLIB's [FAQ-39](https://zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq39);-)

Comment: As you can see in the Scala snippet, I've already set the `nowrap` parameter to `true`, so option 1 doesn't seem right. Since we're having a problem with a situation where C#'s Deflate output works for a specific 3rd part and Scala's output doesn't, I'll try approach 3 first. Thanks for the very detailed explanation

Comment: The deflate is a necessary step since I use it during the encoding of the SAML Request so I don't think using gzip helps (actually I tried it and it broke the SAML SSO flow)

Comment: @Cypherius i've overseen, that you already set nowrap to true. In the meanwhile I've also  checked Java's native code and Microsoft's usage of zlib and it seems that the DeflateStream implementation uses a different default compression level. Please try to set compression level of Deflater to 6 instead of 8 and then compare the output of Scala and C# again.

Comment: None of the available compression levels (0-9) returns the expected result @rmunge